# Loading bigger than memory hdf5 file in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, hdf5, pyspark

I have a big file (say 20 Gb) stored in HDF5 format. The file is basically a set of 3D coordinates that evolve over time (a molecular simulation trajectory). This basically is an array of shape `(8000 (frames), 50000 (particles), 3 (coordinates))`

In regular python I would simply load the hdf5 datafile using for `h5py` or `pytables` and index the datafile like if it was a numpy (the library lazily loads whatever data it needs).

However, if I try to load this file in Spark using `SparkContext.parallelize` it obviously clogs the memory:

```
sc.parallelize(data, 10)
```

How can I handle this problem? Is there a preferred data format for huge arrays? Can I make the rdd to be written on disk without passing by memory?

Comment: I am not quite familiar with hdf5 but is it possible to read it line by line ?
If so you could read sc.textFile('hdf5_file') to read the file and then use some sort of a map function to decode each row

Comment: @anant unfortunately it's a binary (sometime compressed format) I believe it's not possible to read it line by line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spark (and Hadoop) doesn't have support for reading parts of the HDF5 binary files. (I suspect that the reason for this is that HDF5 is a container format for storing documents and it allows to specify tree like hierarchy for the documents).

But if you need to read file from the local disk - it is doable with Spark especially if you know internal structure of your HDF5 file.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/freeman-lab/hdf5-and-spark/blob/master/Spark%20%2B%20HDF5.ipynb) - it assumes that you'll run local spark job, and you know in advance that your HDF5 dataset '/mydata' consists out of 100 chunks.

```
h5file_path="/absolute/path/to/file"

def readchunk(v):
    empty = h5.File(h5file_path)
    return empty['/mydata'][v,:]

foo = sc.parallelize(range(0,100)).map(lambda v: readchunk(v))
foo.count()
```

Going further you can modify the program to detect the number of chunks using `f5['/mydata'].shape[0]`

The next step would be to iterate over multiple datasets (you can list data sets with `f5.keys()`).

Also there is [another article "From HDF5 Datasets to Apache Spark RDDs"](https://hdfgroup.org/wp/2015/03/from-hdf5-datasets-to-apache-spark-rdds/) that describe similar approach.

The same approach would work on a distributed cluster, but it gets little inefficient. h5py requires the file to in on a local file system. So this can be achieved in several ways: copy the file to all workers and keep it under the same location on worker's disk; or put the file to HDFS and mount HDFS using fusefs - so workers could access the file. Both ways have some inefficiencies, but it should be good enough for ad-hoc tasks.

Here is optimized version that opens h5 only once on every executor:

```
h5file_path="/absolute/path/to/file"

_h5file = None    
def readchunk(v):
    # code below will be executed on executor - in another python process on remote server
    # original value for _h5file (None) is sent from driver
    # and on executor is updated to h5.File object when the `readchunk` is called for the first time
    global _h5file
    if _h5file is None:
         _h5file = h5.File(h5file_path)
    return _h5file['/mydata'][v,:]

foo = sc.parallelize(range(0,100)).map(lambda v: readchunk(v))
foo.count()
```

Comment: This is quite a nice way to overcome the issue

Comment: Great answer! But why not move h5.File(h5file_path) outside the readchunk() function? As hdf5 file is opened multiple times in map process.

Comment: @american-curl Good point - as the script is opening the same file for every chunk. But this has to be done carefully when map function will be executed on remote executors. Also pyspark won't be able to serialize h5.File object. So you need some lazy code that would open h5 only once and keep it in global variable. Let me know if you need help writing such code.

Comment: @vvladymyrov Thank you! I do really need some help with the problem. And I met with the similar serialization problem in pyspark. My code is like reading the hdf5.file and hdf5 Dataset in global variables, and then pass to read chunk method. But in pyspark Map stage, it return the error like "h5py/h5py/objects.c: __cinit_() takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given)". It seems that hdf5 dataset does not support direct parallel I/O without opening File first.